# Add time to date_default_timezone_set

Tags: php, xampp

For a weird reason this is still producing a time that is a half hour earlier than the system's time:

```
 date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
```

Is there a way to add minutes to the date_default_timezone_set function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to add time to current time stamp

```
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+1 hours'));
```